# LiquibaseAutoConfiguration Beans tries to load on exclude

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-test

I am getting below error while running the integration test case from intellij even though I have **excluded** the **LiquibaseAutoConfiguration** from the **EnableAutoConfiguration**. What am I missing here?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.checkChangelogExists(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 55 more


Process finished with exit code 255




@ComponentScan 
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
            EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty.class,
            LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class,
            SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
            ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
            SolrAutoConfiguration.class
    })
    @Configuration
    public class App {
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your use of the bare `@ComponentScan` annotation picks up other `@Configuration` classes that are annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` but without the excludes.

Thus, the fix likely involves explicit configuration of what should be picked up via component scanning. See the Javadoc for `@ComponentScan` for further details and options (e.g., `basePackages`, `useDefaultFilters`, `includeFilters`, `excludeFilters`, etc.).